# Inner query to match 'LIKE' results from another table

Tags: mysql, database, sql-like, inner-query

I have a table with data as below:

**FILTER Table**

```
**id    filter**    
4638    Aabe    
4639    Aaby    
4640    Aadl    
4641    Aaga    
4642    Aake
```

**SURNAMES Table**

```
**surnames**    
Aaberge    
Aabehut    
Aabyuti    
Aabytis    
Aadlit    
Aagastha    
Aaker
```

I am trying to write an inner query to retrieve a count of `surnames` that match filters from the `filter` table

Below is what i have based on separate select statements

1. `select * from filter`
2. `select count(*) from surnames where last_name
   like 'Aabe%' or last_name like 'Aaby%' group by last_name;`

How can I write an inner query for this condition since the record count is large?

Comment: `...JOIN on  SURNAMES.surnames  LIKE CONCAT(FILTER.filter,'%')`

Comment: select * from surnames, filters where filters.id > 4215 
JOIN on SURNAMES.last_name LIKE CONCAT(filters.filter,'%')  ?? Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you very much!!

Comment: `select *,COUNT(*) from surnames join filters  on SURNAMES.last_name LIKE CONCAT(filters.filter,'%')    where filters.id > 4215 group by last_name`

Comment: Works. Thank you very much. I dont know how I can mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @Mihai can you please add your comment as an answer so that OP can mark it as accepted and bring closure to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *,
COUNT(*) from surnames join filters 
on SURNAMES.last_name LIKE CONCAT(filters.filter,'%') 
where filters.id > 4215 
group by last_name
```